# Is there any implementation of .NET for Mac OS?

Tags: .net, macos, compatibility, interop

I know this might sound awful.

Is there any implementation of .NET for Mac computers so I can write C++.NET apps for the library (like GTK+ etc.)?

Comment: If you want to compile c++ on a mac, why do you want .net? Especially when you use GTK+?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Mono will run on a mac.](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_on_MacOS_X)

Comment: Note that Mono doesn't implement all .Net features, and doesn't implement the latest version of .Net.  Having said that, it DOES support enough for most applications.

Comment: So is there a C++/VB/C# compiler as well?

Comment: It appears OP wants a C++ solution, which Mono doesn't provide out of the box (yet). However, yes there's a C# compiler.

Comment: @Eric
but mono implements some features .net doesn´t have like LINQDB

Comment: @Patrick: Won't help him if he's looking for a cross-platform solution, unless the users install Mono on .Net (but then, where's the point of implementing the .Net interface ...?)

Comment: @Eric J - mono released their fully-compliant .net 4 implementation _before_ microsoft.  They're missing a few things, but these days it's pretty complete.

Comment: @Eric Also, the question specifically asks about GTK, and so mono is likely to be a very good fit in that respect.  The c++ issue is another story.

Comment: @Shimmy - there are C# and VB.Net compilers (with perhaps F# on the way), but I don't think there's a C++.  And really you'd do yourself a favor to _not_ use C++.Net

Comment: @Eric: my comment wasn´t about the question it was just to say that mono (might?) lack some microsoft .net features but has some other nice features which microsoft .net doesn´t have in return

i just wanted to state that there are two sides of the coin

Comment: @Joel: I'm pretty surprised in a pleasant way. Been a while since I seriously looked at Mono.  I'll be sure and check it out!

Comment: @Patrick: Sure, I just wanted to make it clear that those are Mono features and not .Net features implemented by Mono (and therefore require a Mono install on Windows to use).

Comment: My question is basically if a we can ever make a .NET dll or EXE work on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run Mono on Mac. http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page